# When does webViewDidFinishLoad get fired?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, webkit

Does anyone have a precise understanding of when webViewDidFinishLoad is called on a UIWebViewDelegate?  I've read that it fires once per iframe, if they exist, but I'm concerned about exactly when it loads with respect to the DOM and javascript events.

Is all of the javascript and DOM guaranteed to be downloaded, interpreted and ready by the time this delegate method is called?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

webViewDidFinishLoad is called on a UIWebViewDelegate (as you asked).  webViewDidFinishLoad fires when the entire page is finished downloading, and the javascript has been run and completed.

> Is all of the javascript and DOM guaranteed to be downloaded, interpreted and ready by the time this delegate method is called?

Yes

Comment: This is not true if the page contains iframes, in which case `webViewDidFinishLoad` will be called multiple times.